# laravel passport doesnt support authorization grant type?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am having an issue using the authorization grant in laravel/passport. I usually get this error:

{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","message":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.","hint":"Check the `grant_type` parameter"}

First of all it takes me to login page, when i login it throws the above error. However the password grant works fine.

I created my client using: php artisan passport:client

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try body raw and Content-Type application/json

[image: Passport consume service]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use grant type "client_credentials" you need to create you client using --client option like below:

```
php artisan passport:client --client
```

[Take a look at the Laravel documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens)